# Divide list in sublists by elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings:

```
{"foo", "str1", "str2", ..., "bar", ..., "baz", ...}
```

I need to get sublists of strings between `"foo"`, `"bar"` and `"baz"`.

Is it possible to do this with linq?

**EDIT**

I need a method without looking trough the list twice.

Comment: I would say yes :) Have you already tried something? If yes share it with us.

Comment: Well, I spent two days googling and trying different methods, but didn't find any method that do it without looking twice through the list.

Comment: See my answer for iterating only once. Looks not that nice as the other solutions but also does the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this to fine all elements between any two other elements:

```
var strings = new[] { "foo", "str1", "str2", ... "bar", ... "baz" };
var between = strings.SkipWhile(s => s != "foo").Skip(1)
                     .TakeWhile(s => s != "bar"); // "str1", "str2", ...
```

If you want to get everything between "foo" and "baz", except "bar", use this (assuming the order "foo", "bar", "baz"):

```
var strings = new[] { "foo", "str1", "str2", ... "bar", ... "baz" };
var between = strings.SkipWhile(s => s != "foo").Skip(1)
                     .TakeWhile(s => s != "baz")
                     .Where(s => s != "bar"); // "str1", "str2", ...
```

Or if your comfortable with using Linq queries with side effects, you can do this to partition your input list by certain 'stop' words:

```
 var stops = new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
 var strings = new[] { "foo", "str1", "str2", "bar", "str3", "baz" };
 var p = -1;
 var partitions = 
     from s in strings
     let i = Array.IndexOf(stops, s) 
     group s by p = i == -1 ? p : i into g
     where g.Key == 0 || g.Key == 1
     select g.Skip(1); // { "str1", "str2" }, { "str3" }
```

Or slightly more efficient (since it stops processing after the third stop word):

```
 var partitions = 
     (from s in strings
      let i = Array.IndexOf(stops, s) 
      group s by p = i == -1 ? p : i)
     .SkipWhile(g => g.Key < 0)
     .Take(2)
     .Select(g => g.Skip(1)); // { "str1", "str2" }, { "str3" }
```

Now, this method is a little bit rough around the edges, and it's somewhat fiddly when it comes to items before "foo" or after "baz", but if since you're only looking for items between "foo" and "baz", it should work for you. It has the added benefit that the order of the stop words does not affect the results.

Comment: yes, but I also need a sublist between `"bar"` and `"baz"`. With your method I need to look through the list twice. I am wondering is it possible to do it in one line.

Comment: @dikyyn if you know the order "foo", "bar", "baz" you can just do it in one pass and exclude "bar". See my updated answer.

Comment: I know that it seems to be impossible but I need 2 separate sublists

Comment: what mean Linq queries with side effects? Could you give some links to read about it?

Comment: @dikyyn I mean that the variable `p` is being updated inside the query. This is generally bad practice and can lead to some strange behavior (for example, if you run the query multiple times you'll get different results). But it can be very useful at times.

Answer (score 4):

```
var idxFoo = list.IndexOf("foo");
var idxBar = list.IndexOf("bar");
var idxBaz = list.IndexOf("baz");

var subList1 = list.Skip(idxFoo).Take(idxBar - idxFoo);
var subList2 = list.Skip(idxBar).Take(idxBaz - idxBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate only once through your extensive data list you can do this:

```
List<string> longDataList = new List<string> { "foo", "str1", "str2", "str1", "str2", "str1", "str2", "bar", "str1", "str2", "str1", "str2", "str1", "str2", "baz", "str1", "str2", "str1", "str2", "str1", "str2" };
List<string> splitters = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
Dictionary<string, List<string>> resultDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> currentList = null;
longDataList.ForEach(s =>
    {
       if (splitters.Contains(s))
          {
            if (resultDict.ContainsKey(s))
                currentList = resultDict[s];
             else
                {
                 currentList = new List<string>();
                  resultDict.Add(s, currentList);
                }
           }
        else
           currentList.Add(s);
     });
```

Uses at least a little linq but does the trick iterating only once through your extensive data list.